# Solve the initial value problem $\frac{x'}{t-2}=3tx$, where $x(3)= -4$, and state the interval of existence.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the initial value problem $\frac{x'}{t-2}=3tx$, where $x(3)= -4$, and state the interval of existence.

I got $ x(t)=-4* e^{t^3-3t^2}$, and when asked about interval of existence, I wrote $(-\infty,\infty)$, which was wrong. Later found that in the original $\frac{x'}{t-2}=3tx$, t $\neq$2, it should be $(2,\infty)$.

I am wondering what's the general rule of thumb in finding interval of existence? Is it that 1). both x(t) and $x'$(t) can't be zero; 2). any undefined range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are looking for the largest intervall $I$ such that $2 \notin I$ and $3 \in I.$ Hence $I=(2, \infty).$

Reasons: 1. the differential equation reads $\frac{x'}{t-2}=3tx$, hence $t \ne 2$.

2. the domain of the solution $x$ of the initial value problem has to contain $3$

Answer (score 1):

If $t \ne 2$,
$$\int\frac{dx}{x}=\int 3t(t-2)dt \implies \ln x=t^3-3t^2+C \implies x(t)=D e^{t^3-3t^2}.$$
So we get $$x(t)=-4 e^{t^3-3t^2}, t>2.$$